# Powershell - I'm trying to subtract Mailbox Archive Quota from EXOMailbox TotalItemSize

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I wanted to write a script that will show me total size left on the mailbox. I found out that "Maximum size left" value I need is only shown in Get-Mailbox cmdlet under the "ArchiveQuota" value, and "Size Taken" can only be found in Get-EXOMailboxStatistics under the TotalItemSize value.
I wrote a script that correctly shows me both values and that's fine, but now I need to substract TotalItemSize from ArchiveQuota to achieve "Size Left" value I want. I suppose this is quite a rough approach and I have a feeling that there is a simpler way to do so.

The script I wrote is as follows:

```
$inboxes = Get-Content "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\inboxes.txt"
#this file contains around 12 mailboxes inside


foreach ($inbox in $inboxes)
    {
        Write-Host $inbox
        $size = Get-Mailbox $inbox | Select-Object ArchiveQuota
        $taken = Get-EXOMailboxStatistics $inbox | Select-Object TotalItemSize

        #Write-Host $size
        #Write-Host $taken
        #$result= $size- $taken
        #Write-Host $result
    }
```

I tried converting the value to string and then somehow cut the number value but I quickly gave up on that idea.

> Is there a way to substract those values, or maybe there is a value that shows how many gigs are left in the mailbox?